# Dynamic Facebook-comments-like iFrame resizing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, cross-domain, facebook-iframe

I have content on a different domain which is being pulled into my website via iFrame. The content is hosted on a different domain, and is dynamic content (instant search that pulls up search results).

However, because of the nature of iFrames, unless I set a scroll-bar for the iFrame, content that doesn't fall under the X amount of height WILL NOT BE visible.

I was wondering; Would it be possible to have the iFrame expand (in height) as the content grows within the iFrame?

*A great example of what I'm trying to achieve is the newly-released facebook comments. Facebook lets you have comments on any blog, simply by putting an iFrame in. As you click to load more comments, the iFrame's height expands -- See (in comments section): http://techcrunch.com/2011/03/01/pros-cons-facebook-comments/

Answer (score 0):

Try giving height, width, ***iframe container*** height width to 100% and iframe scroll to *no*

if iframe container has fixed height iframe will have scrolls.

Comment: Hi, I've tried that! That's not really going to work as IF the content of the iFrame is larger than the given height, it won't be shown.